# Excel IF statement when you need to leave a cell blank

Tags: excel

I am a special education teacher creating a data sheet for my staff to use on iPads. The staff use letter codes to indicate if the student responded Independently (I) or needed a prompt.

I was able to write `=if(C10="I",1,0)`.

The students usually complete 10 trials of a task, so I copied the statement for the 10 cells and then averaged the scores in the last cell so that I can create a graph of the data. The issue I am running into is that if the cell is left blank (because the student did not complete 10 trials), the blank cell is scoring as a 0. I need blank cells to be left blank so it is not included in the average.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't have excel on this PC, but have you considered testing first for a value, THEN, testing for the value to include in the average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula to return a blank when C10 is blank, a 1 if C10 contains "I" and a zero for C10 containing anything else:

`=IF(C10="","",IF(C10="I",1,0))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave a cell blank, use `""` in the IF statement, e.g. `if(C10="I",1,"")`.

If you do not want to include blank cells in your average, use function `AVERAGE`. If you want to include them, use function `AVERAGEA`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.I had the if(C10="I",1,0) so that I will get a score of 1 for I and a score of 0 if the para had to give the student a prompt (indicated by several other letters). How can I keep the 1 and 0 scores and have any blank cells remain blank rather than be marked as a 0?

Comment: When I add "" I keep getting a TRUE or FALSE